# Solspace Calender Filtering events by category

Tags: categories, solspace, filter

I am using the demo templates from Solspace and having a bit of trouble getting filtering working. I have one calendar and I want to be able to filter the events based on a category. I can't get it to work. Do I need to create a calendar for every type of category and then just link to each calendar?

Answer (score 1):

No, you definitely do not need to create a calendar for every type of category. You can put all the events into one calendar and filter by category. Just use the [category parameter](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/events/#category) on the `{exp:calendar:events}` tag.

```
{exp:calendar:events category="1"}
```

Instead of hardcoding the category ID you'll probably want to pass it in via a [segment variable](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/url_segments.html). Depending on how you are building your URI's you might find [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) pretty useful.

If that's what you are already trying then please post some template code and I or someone else might be able to give you a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Dynamic Parameters for filtering channels. I'm thinking you can do the same with Category.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/dynamic_parameters.html